# How to call sjs or xqy files from Java api Marklogic 10 [marklogic]

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

Is there a way to call xqy or sjs from my java application, just like I can call a stored procedure in oracle DB?

Another question I have about the xqy or sjs is how to debug them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are multiple ways to invoke JavaScript and XQuery modules in MarkLogic from Java.

Depending upon the type of MarkLogic application server, if it's an HTTP or XDBC, if the modules are installed or if you are sending code to be evaluated, and whether you prefer to use MarkLogic Java APIs or make your own HTTP calls.

You could use the [MarkLogic Java Client API](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/intro) to [invoke a resource service extension](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_27702) or to evaluate your own JavaScript or XQuery with [ServerEvaluationCall](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/eval/ServerEvaluationCall.html):

```
String javascript = "'hello world'";
String response = client.newServerEval()
    .javascript(javascript)
    .evalAs(String.class);
assertEquals("hello world", response);
```

[DataServices](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/DataServices) can be used to expose functionality and build Java client stubs to invoke them.

With XCC you can invoke an installed module with [ModuleInvoke()](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/Session.html#newModuleInvoke-java.lang.String-) or [ModuleSpawn](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/Session.html#newModuleSpawn-java.lang.String-), or eval JavaScript or XQuery with an [AdhocQuery](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/Session.html#newAdhocQuery-java.lang.String-)

You could also make your own calls to the REST [/v1/eval](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval) or [/v1/invoke](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/invoke) endpoints.

As for debugging, you can use [Visual Studio code to connect to a debug enabled appserver](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/visual-studio-code/#connect-to-a-marklogic-debug-server) set breakpoints and step through your JavaScript and XQuery modules.